# Как сделать главную страницей магазина?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно сделать, что бы страница магазина была только на главной.
В настройках wp и woo выбрал нужную страницу.
Проблема в том, что теперь магазин отображается по двум ссылкам
site.loc/,
site.loc/shop

Comment: Удалите страницу shop

Comment: Удалите, как выше пишут, либо (что разумнее) переименуйте slag страницы SHOP в другой. Ибо если у тебя есть одноимённый слаг в имени странички, то и будет открываться.